# java: como acessar um objeto através de uma string

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho um grid com diversas linhas e colunas e cada célula possui uma Label.
Cada Label está nomeada pela coluna e linha (exemplo: ***a1, a2, b1, b2, etc***), tem como eu acessar essas `Labels` através de uma `String`?

Exemplo:

```
private Label a15;

String celula = "a15";

(Label)celula.setText("texto");
```

Comment: Precisa ser `Label` em um `GridPane`?  Não pode utilizar uma `TableView` e mudar a aparência dela com CSS? Tão mais simples de manipular os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método lookup. Ele recebe um id e retorna um node. Mas para usá-lo será necessário setar um id nos labels.

Exemplo:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            Label a1 = new Label("a1");
            a1.setId("a1");
            Label a2 = new Label("a2");
            a2.setId("a2");
            Label b1 = new Label("b1");
            b1.setId("b1");
            Label b2 = new Label("b2");
            b2.setId("b2");
            gridPane.add(a1, 0, 0);
            gridPane.add(a2, 1, 0);
            gridPane.add(b1, 0, 1);
            gridPane.add(b2, 1, 1);


            ((Label)gridPane.lookup("#a2")).setText("texto");

            Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Eu até tinha conseguido de outra forma --

`gridPane.getChildren().filtered(node -> node.getId().equals("a1")).forEach(node -> ((Label)node).setText("texto"));`

-- mas essa sua parece bem mais adequada.